# Regular Expression Star Symbol

Tags: regex, regular-language

Maybe I have missed something, but what are wrong with this regular expresion?

```
var str = "lorem ipsum 12345 dolor";
var x = /\d+/.exec(str);
var y = /\d*/.exec(str);
console.log(x); // will print 12345
console.log(y); // will print "" but why ?
```

Can you please explain why `/\d*/.exec(str);` returns an empty string instead of "12345".  `*` means zero or more number of matches.

Comment: According to http://regexpal.com/, using "lorem ipsum 12345 dolor" and "\d*" as the string/regex, it matches just fine... What language are you using your regex in?

Comment: @Nightfirecat - That looks like JavaScript.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\d*` matches zero or more digits in a row. When you run `exec` on a regex, it starts at the beginning of the input and returns the **first** instance it finds of your given pattern.

So where is the first instance of `\d*` in that string? Well, it's the first position in the string that has *zero or more* numbers after it. But they *all* have zero or more numbers after them! Either there are numbers there, or there aren't, but either way it matches. So the first instance of `\d*` is simply a zero-length substring beginning at the first position in the string.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this explains everything.

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker - Thanks for catching my typo!

Answer (score 1):

`*` matches zero or more. Maybe I'm wrong, but wouldn't this match zero digits starting at "lorem", hence the empty string?