# how to remove all zero's from a string's beginning in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to get rid of the 0's before the strings. tried using TrimStart method, but it didn't work. If anyone could help, that'd be great.

Comment: your string contains only numbers?

Comment: Please show your data, your code, and tell the details of the problems with your code. Else this question degrades into little more than a `"please give me the code"` type question, which isn't appropriate for this site. Also please go through the [tour] and do take a look at the [help] section as well as the [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section, so that your questions and answers will be better making your future experiences here better.

Comment: I have strings like 00000000000000823841 and 00000000000000000896.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with

```
Integer.parseInt(mystring);
```

then you can continue with the integer or do a

```
String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(mystring));
```

In order to get the string again without left 0´s.

Note that this only will work if your string only contains numerics values. If your values are long numbers, you can use Long instead of Integer

Comment: thank you so much! I've been stuck for a while

Comment: You are welcome! please up-vote the answer and/or accept it if you think is the correct one. Thanks! glad to help you

Comment: @FranciscoHernandez What if the number exceeds the maximum value of a Long?

Comment: In this case you can use BigInteger instead in that way: String.valueOf(new BigInteger(mystring)) or use your solution too. Your solution is pretty good

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a [RegEx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for this and the [`String#replaceFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method

---

### Solution

```
System.out.println("00000120003".replaceFirst("0*", "")); // Prints : 120003
```

---

[**Explaination over the * in Regex**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865159/regular-expression-star-symbol)

---

### [`String#replaceFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

> Replaces the first substring of this string that matches the given
>   regular expression with the given replacement.

Comment: @Thevenin Not when using `String#replaceFirst()` but it is indeed the case when using `String#replaceAll()`

Comment: @Thevenin What example do you have in mind? Because I do not get exactly in which situation it wouldn't be correct to use `0*`

Comment: @Thevenin Have you tried it? Try this : `System.out.println("2200000033".replaceFirst("0*", ""));` prints `2200000033`

Comment: Ok you're right but I don't see why 0* does not match in 12003.

Comment: @Thevenin, I was wondering the same thing. I've never used a regex before, but I was just looking at the Pattern class where it defines all the special characters. The `0*`, matches `0 or more` instances of the digit. So, the start of the String does match the regex so nothing is replaced with nothing? Since we are doing a `replaceFirst` the matching stops there. If you use `0+` which matches on `1 or more` then the middle zeroes are replaced.

Comment: @camickr thank you very much. Much clearer now.